# Slide Toggle issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Sorry for my crazy question. I have some nav link. By mouseover the links the black background slide from top to bottom and links move to bottom to top. I found two scripts. It works well. But i want to combine both animation. Please see my fiddle location. Any ideas??

http://jsfiddle.net/DpZJE/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you meant this?
not using the slideToggle, and instead using thew slideDown and slideUp

```
  $("li.first").hover(function () {
     $(".trans1").slideUp("slow");
     $("li.first a.link").animate({"paddingTop": "-=30px"}, "slow");
   },function () {
     $(".trans1").slideDown("slow");
     $("li.first a.link").animate({"paddingTop": "+=30px"}, "slow");
   });
```

(added the yellow background for debugging..)
http://jsfiddle.net/avipinto/DpZJE/10/

Comment: really... accepted this one....? jesus

Answer (score 2):

Combine? Like this?

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DpZJE/2/)

You can use the [hover](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) method, which is a combination of mouseenter and mouseleave.

```
$("li.first a.link").hover(function(){
    $("li.first a.link").animate({"paddingTop": "-=30px"}, "slow");
}, function(){
    $("li.first a.link").animate({"paddingTop": "+=30px"}, "slow");
});
```

Comment: Liking the `hover()` functionality - still prefer `on()` though ;)

Comment: @Neurofluxation Well, i would still say that `hover` is more "combined" than `on` ;)

Answer (score 2):

**EDITED FOR BETTER FIDDLING ;)**


or like this?
http://jsfiddle.net/neuroflux/DpZJE/9/ 
(with `stop()` animation)
http://jsfiddle.net/neuroflux/DpZJE/13/

Snippet (note the lack of `hover()`):

```
$("li").on('mouseover', function () {
  $(this).children('span').slideToggle("slow");
  $(this).children('a').animate({"paddingTop": "-=30px"}, "slow");
}).on('mouseout', function() {
     $(this).children('span').slideToggle("slow");
     $(this).children('a').animate({"paddingTop": "+=30px"}, "slow");
});
```

Comment: How can I stop animation when I'm continuously mousein and mouseout very fast. I have already tried stop() but it's not working?

Comment: That's because of `slidetoggle` ... hold on...

Comment: Edited answer - second fiddle!